# XPath evaluate kills a script in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xpath

I am running a simple document.evaluate() with a simple XPath expression on this node:

```
<li class="comment-block"> 
<div class="comment-icon"> 
    <a href="address.com" class="comment-buddy-icon-link">Address</a> 
</div> 
<div class="comment-content"> 
    <p class="comment-head"> 
        <span class="comment-owner"> 
            <span class="comment-author-container">
                <a href="http://some.address.com">Some Address</a>
            </span> 
        </span> 
        <small class="comment-meta"> 
            Some text
        </small> 
    </p> 
    <div class="comment-body"> 
        <p>Some more Text</p> 
    </div> 
</div>
</li>
```

The XPath string is:
`div[contains(@class, 'comment-content')]`. This works fine in Firefox and breaks in Chrome. There are no exceptions thrown in Chrome, the script simply exits. I don't understand why this would break, the situation seems to be straightforward, select a child div of the li element, whose class is "comment-content".

What is interesting, another XPath string `.//div[contains(@class, 'comment-content')]` works fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select `div` direct children of the context node, there's a Webkit bug that I fixed in December: [XPath expressions that start with `div` are treated as syntax errors](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50366). The fix is in the Dev Channel build of Chrome (10), but it's not in stable (9). For now, you'll have to use `./div`, which means the same thing as `div`.

Comment: By the way, you can use these pathological expressions (e.g. "div div div") to check whether you have the newest Chrome.  http://trac.webkit.org/export/latest/trunk/LayoutTests/fast/xpath/ambiguous-operators.html